# Law of Cosines to find length C in Python

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

```
import math

def len_side(a,b,C):
    c_rad = math.radians(C)
    c = math.acos(c_rad)
    print(c)
    c_sq = c**2
    c_sq = (a**2) + (b**2) - (2*a*b*(math.cos(c)))
    if C > 360:
        print(False)
    else:
        return c
```

The code should find the length of side c but does not return the expected value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have made a mistake in translating the cosine rule formula into code, the line `c = math.acos(c_rad)` seems a little strange to me. `c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - a*b*cos(C)`

```
import math


def len_side(a, b, C):
    C_rad = math.radians(C)
    c_sq = a ** 2 + b ** 2 - 2 * a * b * math.cos(C_rad)
    c = math.sqrt(c_sq)
    return c
```